# Add a simulated camera to an Android device

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

Short version : I'd like to add a simulated camera to an Android device.

Long version : I am developing an Android app on two Android devices : A and B. I want the A's camera to send its stream to B, and I want B to handle it as if it was a camera of its own. So B would have this "fake camera" fed by A's stream. But this "fake camera" has to act like a real one.
The connection between those two is done, the stream sending/receiving is correctly done, and I'm able to display it on B'screen. But I have no clue how to simulate it as an extra camera of the B's device.

If you have any tips for me, I would be glad to ear about it.
Thanks.

PS : The stream sent/dreceived is a GLSurfaceView

Comment: can you build a custom ROM for device B?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new camera on your device is possible only if you are builing your own ROM & flashing it on your device .

Android not exposing any  any API to add Camera

As a normal user/developer the app doesn't have any access to add a new Camera instance.

Camera instances are linked with  framwork -> HAL -> Camera H/W

It's is only possible to add new fake camera only from the framwork or HAL side, to access fake camera using android Camera API as real Camera .

As a developer ,
  Only on your app you can display like camera ,Just by GUI like other camera app (Not possible by Camera API)